# Chini's ODE (generalized Lotka-Volterra model)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following differential equation system and I would like to give the p(t), n(t) functions explicitly.

$$\frac{dn}{dt} = (\xi-\alpha)np-\xi n^{2} \quad (1)\\
\frac{dp}{dt} = (\xi-\alpha)np-\xi p^{2} \quad (2)$$

If I express the p(t) variable from the first equation and substitute it to the second equation I get the next differential equation where a, b and c are constants.

$$\ddot{n}n+a\dot{n}n^{2}+b\dot{n}^{2}-cn^{4}=0 \\
a = \frac{\alpha(\xi-\alpha)+2\xi^{2}}{\xi-\alpha}\\
b = \frac{\alpha}{\xi-\alpha}\\
c = \frac{\alpha\xi(\alpha-2\xi)}{\xi-\alpha}$$

If I label the first derivative of n by y then this equation becomes a Chini's ODE:

$$ \dot{n} = y \qquad \ddot{n}=\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dn}\frac{dn}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dn}y\\
ny\frac{dy}{dn}+ayn^{2}+by^{2}-cn^{4}=0\\
\frac{dy}{dn} = -an-\frac{by}{n}+\frac{cn^{3}}{y}$$

In this case the Chini's equation is solvable since the Chini invariant independent from n and we can make the differential eqaution separable with the following transformation.

$$ y(n) = n^{2}v(n)$$

Wolfram alpha gives a complicated solution for v(n) in an implicit equation therefore I can't go on. (I have tried to simplifying it with respect to that the constants a,b and c contains $\alpha$ and $\xi$ and it will be nice but it remains implicit.)
[image: Solution of Chini's equation]

Could someone help me to solve the original differential equation system with an other method? Maybe the system similar to generalized Lotka-Volterra model with two species.

Comment: When you subtract the second ODE from the first you obtain $$\frac{d(n-p)}{dt}=-\xi(n+p)(n-p),$$ and if $\xi>0$ and we are in the first quadrant then all solutions are attracted, as $t\to\infty$, toward the half-line $n=p$, $n,p\ge0$.  Have you tried such an approach?